# The use of "I would"

Tags: would

Can I use "I would" for making suggestions?
For example, "I would do this thing instead of this" or "I would eat healthy food in order to lose weight". Can use it in that way without saying "if I was you" at the beginning?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: While they have broadly similar meanings, *I would* and *If I were you I would* are clearly different. Which you should use depends on what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

If you're saying it then emphasize the 'I'. If you're writing it out, you could use "I would" as well as " So and so is a possibility"

Comment: "I would do this" is a perfectly normal way of making a suggestion; it can be preceded or followed by "if I were you", but would be understood without.